# Which hotfix rollups are required for DXA 1.2

Tags: dxa

SDL DXA 1.2 prerequisites states "DXA 1.2 requires SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1"

Which specific hotfix rollups are required for DXA 1.2?

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659

Comment: Which part of SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 **HR1** is not clear?

Comment: The location of the download is not clear, I was looking in https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx is not the right place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hotfix Roll up for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 is available at SDLTridionWorld (requires login to download). The documentation for the installation is available [HERE](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-1D775071-CA2D-4CAE-8742-77A96AB19E9B).

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/patches/SDLTridion2013/index.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx

Comment: @ChrisMills common mistake I guess, the best way to find the correct location is to just follow the documentation. So whenever there is a mention in the DXA documentation about SDL Tridion, you can find more info about that in that documentation (maybe we should consider links accross publications there ;o). https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0A7564A7-DB20-448B-9965-88C7FE7DF7B9 will tell you the exact download location and steps you need.

Answer (score 4):

The list of hotfixes contained in 2013 SP1 HR1 can be found in the [online documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-E3179627-AD2D-493C-A2E0-FC396E7806F7).

DXA 1.2 was most likely built on HR1 systems, so I don't believe there will be any documentation as to whether any of those particular hotfixes are necessary for it to work. I guess my question would be, "Why wouldn't you install HR1?"

Comment: To clarify: the DXA 1.2 web application framework was built against, tested against and ships with 2013 SP1 HR1 CD libraries.

Comment: I will install HR1 now that I know the correct download